# When or why would I use a the node package duplexer ( or similar)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been picking up Node.js for a while now and I am currently working through the [nodeschool.io Stream-adventure](http://nodeschool.io/#stream-adventure) tutorials and I have just completed the duplexer challenge. While I understand what its doing my knowledge of and experience with Stream in generally is minimal at best and I can't find an example or explanation I can follow as to when or why I might do this. Obviously I have read the [documentation](https://npmjs.org/package/duplexer) for duplexer but what I'm looking for is for some possible real world scenarios where It would be useful/require, specific node cases would be preferable but non-node examples welcome too.

Answer (score 0):

Duplex streams are typically used for communications, but RPC typically also use duplex.

An easy to understand analogy is a phone. When you speak to someone on the phone, you are using full-duplex communication, whereas a walkie-talkie (where you push-to-talk) is using half-duplex.

For a node-specific use case, have a look at this link:
http://smartmobilestudio.com/2014/01/08/server-side-node-js-part-2/